# Lazy Load with normal DOM inside specified class?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'd like to use lazy load images (e.g. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload ).

The problem is I want to integrate without rewriting the img tags with  src="1px.gif" data-original="foo1.jpg".
Instead I'd like to simply add the images as I used to (e.g. in CMS etc.) inside a certain class, e.g.

```
<div class="lazyLoad">
  <img src="foo1.jpg" width="800px" height="600px" alt="foo1" />
  <img src="foo2.jpg" width="800px" height="600px" alt="foo2" />
</div>
```

would turn it on page load into

```
<div class="lazyLoad">
  <img src="1px.gif" data-original="foo1.jpg" width="800px" height="600px" alt="foo1" />
  <img src="1px.gif" data-original="foo2.jpg" width="800px" height="600px" alt="foo2" />
</div>
```

which then would do it's actual lazy load magic.

Does somebody know a solution for this?

Comment: for a first shot solution you need to modify your CMS a little bit while adding images using that

Comment: the CMS was just an example for images being added via markup

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you also control how to CMS provides the information to the frontoffice you can just exchange que placeholders for the following variables.

If you can't do it server side (php/asp/etc) and you can inject some javascript into it you can **use `jQuery` to, right after the DOM has loaded but the images haven't, do that change on it's own**. It won't be as elegant as the first solution (because your browser will probably preload some images) but all in all it will work.

```
// jQuery example
$(".lazyLoad img").each(function(index) {               // selects all img within lazyLoad
   $(this).attr('data-original', $(this).attr('src'));  // inserts a new attribute with the original src
   $(this).attr('src', "1px.gif");                      // put src as the 1px.gif
});
```

[**You can see an implementing of it in jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WvA4V/31/)
(click the *results* pane to load the images)

**This is proof of concept. I would highly recommend you do this server side!**

Comment: You're right. Images may load already before the DOM is changed to data-original. That would end up in 2 http requests per displayed image.

Comment: @Martin, not really (on the two requests)... the browser will cache and realize it's the same request if you pass the image with the correct cache parameters. You may load some images that are off the viewport (few).

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work. Tried with 100 images and it loads them all.

Comment: @Martin, as I told this was pseudo-code... and my jQuery was non-functioning. Just tested on my machine and got a high success rate. Also made the code working.